# JQUERY .keyup Event Not Working Properly

Tags: jquery

I have a jquerymobile site.  One of the pages has a search box with a .keyup event.

When you start typing or press enter it triggers this event.

If I get to this page from my homepage the triggers don't work.  If I'm on this page and i reload the page then the trigger works.  The site is all one file with different DIVs as pages.

The only way it works is if I reload the page first.

Any ideas? Thanks
This is loaded in a header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup ({  
                cache: false  
            });  

$("#gsearch").keyup(function(event) {
                clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
                var wait = setTimeout(gsearch, 600);
                $(this).data('timer', wait);
            }); 



            function gsearch() {
                var len = 0;
                var searchdata = '';
                searchdata = $("#gsearch").val();
                len = searchdata.length;
                if ( len >= 2 ) {
                //$("#gtemp").html("<center><img src='ajax-loader.gif'></center>");
                //$.mobile.pageLoading();
                    $.ajax({  
                         // code here
                }
                    });

                }

            }
```

This is the search box

```
<center>
                <div align="center" style="padding:5px; text-align:center;">
                <input type="search" id="gsearch" value="" />
                </div>
            </center>

            <div  id="googleres">
```

Comment: Could you post some code

Comment: A guess would be that you are registering the event handler before the page is loaded, but that's a wild guess - nobody can actually know anything beyond wild guesses without seeing relevant code.

Comment: it seems to work in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6Lzaz/  Are you loading jQuery first? Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: It seems you have an extra `}` there in the `.ajax({}});` Could that be your problem?

Comment: @james well the code works if i reload the page. The extra } is just a bad paste.

Comment: @james Yes the jquery is loaded first and all inside <head>. I'm using one file for the site.  There are no javascript errors

Comment: @vpets Are you moving page via ajax/ dynamically loading the page? I would also try defining gsearch outside of the document `.ready()` function

Comment: @vpets. I just noticed your line: " The site is all one file with different DIVs as pages." that means you are loading the page dynamically... Refer to Switz's answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Works fine here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5LEbh/

`.keyup` works fine, your code inside must be wrong

if you're dynamically loading the search box you need to use:

```
$("#gsearch").live("keyup", function(event) {
  //run code
}
```

Comment: Well like I said before it works fine if I just reload the page.  It doesn't work if I load the homepage first then flip to the page with the search input box.

Comment: Are you dynamically loading the search input box? see above

Comment: no the search box is always there.  only the content returned by the search is dynamically loaded

Comment: @vpets you are dynamically loading the page : "The site is all one file with different DIVs as pages."

Comment: @james - I'm using jquerymobile so entire site with all the pages is loaded.  Each page is a <div data-role="page"  ...> and just switching between pages doens't reload the page.   So thats not dynamically loading a page, right?

Comment: cc@james @switz Using the code worked.  Can you explain to me why. Why is this considered dynamically loaded?

Comment: Using `.keyup` binds the function to all elements currently on the page.  Using `.live` binds the function to all current elements and all future elements. You are dynamically adding the elements to the page.  If you want to see this, view the HTML in Firebug before you "change" the page and watch as the element is added.

Comment: @vpets I haven't gotten into jQuery mobile yet but i beleive it does the ajax loading for you: "jQuery Mobile includes automatic AJAX page loading of external pages ...." from http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/pages/index.html

Comment: Just an fyi if anyone is having any issues, Firefox on Android behaves incorrectly, doesn't respond to keyup, and only responds to keypress/keydown on return. You should look at the documented change function as a compromise - I just use that event to fire the keyup event.

Comment: @switz I dont know if that is machine related thing but I have noticed that jQuery keyup handler doesnt fire when the key is pressed softly.